# Call to undefined method App\User::messages()", exception: "BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-websockets

I am following this library for chat and i use presence channel in it

```
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets
```

whenever i send a message console show me this error in my chatcontoller

```
Call to undefined method App\User::messages()", exception: "BadMethodCallException
```

my controller

```
class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('chats');
    }

    public function fetchMessages()
    {
        return Message::with('user')->get();
    }

    public function sendMessage(Request $request)
    {
        $message = auth()->user()->messages()->create([
            'message' => $request->message
        ]);

        broadcast(new MessageSent($message->load('user')))->toOthers();

        return ['status' => 'success'];
    }
```

User.php

```
public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }
```

Message.php

```
class Message extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'messages';

    protected $fillable = ['message'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

why my message is not delivering to other user

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
    $message = auth()->user()->messages()->create([
        'message' => $request->message
    ]);

    $user = User::find(auth()->id);
    $message = $user->messages()->create([
        'message' => $request->message
    ]);
```

I believe auth()->user();  is different than the User::class

Comment: it returns me with that error : "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found"

Comment: You have to “use” the classes in the controller heading.